# Get params info for any function like g_signal_query

Tags: c++, gtk

I'm abstracting any signal with

```
g_signal_query(g_signal_lookup (name_of_signal, G_OBJECT_TYPE (instance_of_gtk_object)), &signal_info);

callback_object->signal_id = signal_info.signal_id;
callback_object->signal_name = signal_info.signal_name;
callback_object->itype = signal_info.itype;
callback_object->signal_flags = signal_info.signal_flags;
callback_object->return_type = signal_info.return_type;
callback_object->n_params = signal_info.n_params;
callback_object->param_types = signal_info.param_types;

[...]

closure = g_cclosure_new_swap (G_CALLBACK (connect_callback), callback_object, NULL);
int ret = g_signal_connect_closure (instance, callback_event, closure, after);
```

As you can see, this give-me a list of [GSignalQuery](https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/struct.SignalQuery.html) with name, GType, position of argument, etc. So I create a struct and pass this to a generic function. On this function I read this struct and loop between VA list creating GValues back

Now i'm abstracting any others functions, like [gtk_tree_selection_selected_foreach](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.TreeSelection.selected_foreach.html), [GtkTreeViewRowSeparatorFunc](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.TreeView.get_row_separator_func.html), or any other function to a generic callback

My question: is there a way to get a list of paramters the function expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you use [GObject introspection](https://gi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which provides metadata (both in XML and in binary form) to describe a C ABI. The introspection data is commonly used by language bindings, which is essentially what you're doing.

Comment: this looks like a good solution! but when i call this generic function its signature differs from the expected function and it shows `invalid conversion from ‘bool (*)(...)’ to ‘GtkTreeSelectionForeachFunc’ {aka ‘void (*)(_GtkTreeModel*, _GtkTreePath*, _GtkTreeIter*, void*)’}`, its becase my generic function looks like `generic_callback(gpointer user_data, ...)`. Any advise?

Comment: You'll need to cast the function pointer to the appropriate type.

Comment: ah I got. The error is about return type, and not the paramters. Thank you!